# Doesn't it seem like there wasn't enough time for everything to happen during the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars

Looking at all the novels and comics that take place during the Clone Wars, the TCW comics, the UK comic strips and even mentions of past happenings like Anakin's 100+ arrests during the Clone Wars, it doesn't seem like Anakin and Obi-Wan could have accomplished all their missions and battles in the span of three years that the Clone Wars lasted.

Were they doing things every single day, or two things in a day? Help me if I'm wrong, is it plausible that they could've done all the things that have been portrayed or mentioned in the span of three standard years?

Comment: Galactic standard years... which is how ever long lucas needs it to be for the story.

Comment: Just consider how many Christmas episodes MASH had.

Answer (score 3):

To me it does seem plausible, though perhaps pushing believability.

There are approximately 1,100 days in the Clone Wars (assuming a 365 day year). I would estimate there are approximately 300-400 comics/episodes/books/etc that have been set during the Clone Wars (based on Wookieepedia's [Timeline of media](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_media)). Some could have occured on the same day, others are established to occur over multiple days, so I figure it balances out to about the same number of days covered. Obviously, ones that do not have any of the same characters could be set concurrently. If the rest of the time is downtime/travel time, it seems believable to me that everything could have occurred, though perhaps it is a bit cramped.